# How can I set up network access between two Kubernetes clusters deployed in Minikube?

Tags: kubernetes, networking, minikube

I've got two clusters set up with Minikube via Minikube's 'profiles' feature. I'd like to be able to access Ingress resources available on one cluster from the other cluster. However, I'm consistently getting "Connection refused".

I'm on Linux, using kvm2 as my driver. I can access hosts on the Internet from the pods, I can access the Ingress I've configured from the host OS, but I can't seem to access the Ingress exposed in the other cluster's bridge from the other cluster.

Here's the routing setup after configuring the two K8s clusters as separate Minikube profiles.

```bash
❯ ip route
default via 192.168.111.1 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp src 192.168.111.242 metric 2003
127.0.0.0/8 via 127.0.0.1 dev lo
192.168.39.0/24 dev virbr1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.39.1
192.168.50.0/24 dev virbr2 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.50.1
192.168.111.0/24 dev wlp4s0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.111.242 metric 2003
192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.1
```

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default minikube profiles are isolated from each other.
The work around here is easy, just create two nodes instead and set it up that way.

more at:
https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/tutorials/multi_node/

```
minikube start --nodes 2 -p multinode-demo
```

Comment: Ah! I will try that and come back with a big green check if it works, which I think it will! Thanks, @invertedOwlCoding!

Comment: ok let me know! I had a similar use case and it worked fine, just do minikube node list and configure them accordingly..

Comment: So, this doesn't answer the case of needing two separate K8s clusters 'side-by-side' on a host. However, it does help, and is really the only answer until and unless the Minikube devs add multi-cluster within a single bridge as a feature - or some other network-level solution. Thanks! I'll mark it as Accepted.

Comment: Oh ok, does the infra/design allow you to expose them via a nodePort? that way the multi cluster can communicate . but wow, thanks i can finally comment now ! much appreciated Jesse